# Remove duplication from regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm using following regex, but as you can see there is much recursion in the expression.
Is there a better way to solve this?
What I need is kind of a "jump" operator.

```
((letzter|voriger|letztes|voriges) (lied|title|song))( (höhren|abspielen))?|((lied|title|song)( (wiederholen|erneut (höhren|abspielen))))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://debuggex.com/r/ZN4uGdQss3CDTar9)

Comment: Just to get your vocabulary right: there is no *recursion* in your pattern, there's *duplication*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCRE implements [subroutine calls](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html), to achieve *exactly* what you need.

- `(?P<groupname>subpattern)` defines a group.
- `\g<groupname>` calls the group.

**Regex:**

```
/
(?:(?P<relative>letzte[rs]|vorige[rs])[ ])?        # optional non-capturing group
(?P<what>lied|title|song)
(?(relative)                                       # IF group <relative> was matched
    (?:[ ](?P<action>höhren|abspielen))?           # another optional non-capturing group
  |
    [ ](wiederholen|erneut[ ]\g<action>)           # subroutine call to group <action>
)
/ix
```

---

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8n2dA_tWie55SUOh)

---

PCRE allows some ways to define a group, all of them with the same meaning:

- `(regex)` Group
- `(?P<name>regex>` Group named *name*.
- `(?'name'regex)` Group named *name*.
- `(?<name>regex)` Group named *name*.

as well as different ways to make subroutine call:

- `(?3)` Recurse/call group 3.
- `\g<3>` Recurse/call group 3.
- `\g'3'` Recurse/call group 3.
- `(?-1)` Recurse/call previous group.
- `\g<-1>` Recurse/call previous group.
- `\g'-1'` Recurse/call previous group.
- `\g<-1>` Recurse/call previous group.
- `(?&name)` Recurse/call group named *name*.
- `(?P>name)` Recurse/call group named *name*.
- `\g<name>` Recurse/call group named *name*.
- `\g'name'` Recurse/call group named *name*.

Comment: Notice I also used [`(?:non-capturing)` groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [`(?(IF)true|false)` conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!